# Get first and last record number in every date exists in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

I am trying to show invoices for every single day, so for that purpose I used group by on created date and sum on subtotal. This is how I done it :

```
  SELECT 
         `main_table`.*, 
         SUM(subtotal) AS `total_sales` 
  FROM 
        `sales_invoice` AS `main_table` 
  GROUP BY 
        DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%y")
```

Its working, but I also want to get the Invoice # from and Invoice # to for every date. Is it possible to do it with single query ?

**EDIT :**

**Table Structure :**

```
------------------------------------------------
| id | inoice_no | created_at           | subtotal

| 1  | 34        | 2015-03-17 05:55:27  | 5 
| 2  | 35        | 2015-03-17 12:35:00  | 7
| 3  | 36        | 2015-03-20 01:40:00  | 3
| 4  | 37        | 2015-03-20 07:05:13  | 6 
| 5  | 38        | 2015-03-20 10:25:23  | 1
| 6  | 39        | 2015-03-24 12:00:00  | 6
------------------------------------------------
```

**Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id | inoice_no | created_at           | subtotal | total_sales

| 2  | 35        | 2015-03-17 12:35:00  | 7        | 12
| 5  | 38        | 2015-03-20 10:25:23  | 1        | 10
| 6  | 39        | 2015-03-24 12:00:00  | 6        | 6
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**What I Expect**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| id | inoice_no | created_at           | subtotal | total_sales | in_from | in_to

| 2  | 35        | 2015-03-17 12:35:00  | 7        | 12          | 34      | 35
| 5  | 38        | 2015-03-20 10:25:23  | 1        | 10          | 36      | 38
| 6  | 39        | 2015-03-24 12:00:00  | 6        | 6           | 39      | 39
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Show us the Table structure. Also Sample output.

Comment: Also if you could use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to recreate the tables, it would be easier to come up with a query.

Comment: How do you determine which `invoice_id` is `to` and which `invoice_id` is `from`. I am unable to see a pattern . Please clarify .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your invoice number is INTEGER then below query will give you the result what you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.created_at, "%m-%y") AS InvoiceDate, 
       MIN(A.invoiveNo) AS FromInvoiceNo, 
       MAX(A.invoiveNo) AS ToInvoiceNo, 
       SUM(A.subtotal) AS total_sales 
FROM sales_invoice AS A 
GROUP BY InvoiceDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess salesid is primaryid in sales_invoice table.

```
select * from(
 SELECT 
         `main_table`.*, 
         SUM(subtotal) AS `total_sales` 
  FROM 
        `sales_invoice` AS `main_table` 
  GROUP BY 
        DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%y")
  order by main_table.salesid  limit 1
  union all

 SELECT 
         `main_table`.*, 
         SUM(subtotal) AS `total_sales` 
  FROM 
        `sales_invoice` AS `main_table` 
  GROUP BY 
        DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%y")
  order by main_table.salesid desc limit 1
  )a
```